# Type Cast on void method in Java

Tags: java, android

I am wondering what the type cast **(e)** in the code below? Is it a type cast?

in Activity onCreate()-method:

```
final Button buttonEval = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mainFragmentButtonMoodEval);
buttonEval.setOnClickListener((e) imageButtonClicked(DbOpenHandler.MOOD_GOOD));
```

Here is the definition of imageButtonClicked():

```
private void imageButtonClicked(int mood){ ... }
```

UPDATE: My textbook has written **->** between the (e) and the start of the method call. I thought this is a way to tell me that the code example will extend the line. Now it seems that **->** is a symbol related to Java. :-)

UPDATE-2: here are the code snippets related to the textbook, so you can see yourself: https://github.com/tkuenneth/begleitmaterialien-zu-android-7/blob/master/Kapitel10/TKMoodley_CP/app/src/main/java/com/thomaskuenneth/tkmoodley/TKMoodley.java

Comment: Where did you get this code? It shouldn't even compile...

Comment: It's not a type cast; it's invalid syntax. It's most similar to the optional parentheses around the arguments of a lambda: `(e) -> imageButtonClicked(...)` (optional at least for a single parameter).

Comment: Great - I thought '->' means 'jump to next line' in the textbook with the code.